# MySQL COUNT IF not working and giving all 0s

Tags: mysql, sql, count, left-join

By using left join, I'm trying to count the number of shapes with existing purchases (0 if no purchase). I also group them by shape type. But the result I'm getting are all 0s.

Table shapes:

```
id  shape     colour
1   circle    red
2   rectangle blue
3   triangle  green
4   star      yellow
5   cross     purple
6   moon      orange
```

Table shape_purchase:

```
id  price
3   3.24
2   1.95
3   5.42
4   6.32
5   4.21
1   7.45
3   5.97
3   4.31
1   6.32
4   7.82
```

**SQL:
`SELECT shapes.shape, COUNT(IF(shape_purchase.price != NULL, 1, NULL)) FROM shapes LEFT JOIN shape_purchase ON shapes.id = shape_purchase.id GROUP BY shapes.id` <- What's wrong here?**

Result:

```
shape      COUNT(IF(shape_purchase.price != NULL, 1, NULL))
circle     0
rectangle  0
triangle   0
star       0
cross      0
moon       0
```

Is there something wrong with the fact I'm calling shape_purchase.price? Or does left join make things more complicated?

FYI, `SELECT * FROM shapes LEFT JOIN shape_purchase ON shapes.id = shape_purchase.id` looks like this:

```
id  shape      colour  id    price
3   triangle   green   3     3.24
2   rectangle  blue    2     1.95
3   triangle   green   3     5.42
4   star       yellow  4     6.32
5   cross      purple  5     4.21
1   circle     red     1     7.45
3   triangle   green   3     5.97
3   triangle   green   3     4.31
1   circle     red     1     6.32
4   star       yellow  4     7.82
6   moon       orange  NULL  NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost any comparison to `NULL` is `NULL` -- which is treated as false.  Including inequality.  That is why SQL has `IS NULL` and `IS NOT NULL`.

However, I would recommend writing your code as:

```
SELECT s.shape, COUNT(sp.price)
FROM shapes s LEFT JOIN
     shape_purchase sp
     ON s.id = sp.id
GROUP BY s.id;
```

`COUNT(<expression>)` counts the non-`NULL` values.  There is no need for conditional logic.

Comment: hey you're right about count not counting NULL values. I thought any entry will be counted